# Comprobar tipo componente padre desde hijo en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

¿Existe alguna manera de comprobar desde el componente hijo el padre en el que se esta cargando?

Lo comento por que tengo ciertos componentes que se abren de varias ventanas y en algunas de ellas tienen comportamientos especificos

Se que se puede hacer con la ruta, pero quería saber si se puede comprobar el padre desde el que se abre (sin inyectarlo)

Comment: ¿No sería más sencillo hacerlo al revés, que el padre tenga la responsabilidad de decirle al hijo (mediante algún parámetro @Input) cómo debe mostrarse?

Comment: Al tenerlo en muchas ventanas, me requiere modifcar todas, por lo tanto, no, lo veo mucho mas costoso de tiempo